# How to make text behave as a hyperlink in PDF exported from Adobe InDesign 5.5

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

I have a long text with some hyperlinks in it. All hyperlinks except of one are automaticaly recognised and behave in PDF as hyperlink. One not. How to do it manually?

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried, Scott answers should have worked. Highlight the text, and use the Hyperlink panel to add the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a way to ad hyperlinks in a illustrator document?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16019/is-there-a-way-to-ad-hyperlinks-in-a-illustrator-document)

Comment: @ZachSaucier The duplicate you suggested is for Illustrator. The OP is using Indesign 5.5

Answer (score 7):

There are two things required for creating functional hyperlinks in a PDF from InDesign:

1. Link defined in `Hyperlinks` panel
2. PDF Export supporting hyperlinks.

If you've already created the definition in the `Hyperlinks` panel as @Scott recommended, then my bet is that you are using an PDF export that doesn't support interactivity, and those hyperlink settings are being ignored when generating the PDF.

I don't have version 5.5, so I can't verify exactly what your screens look like, but in CC, there are two ways to include interactive elements - it should be similar for you:

### Option 1

Select `Adobe PDF (Interactive)` when choosing the filename:
[image: Interactive PDF]
Then set whatever options you like on the Export Settings dialogue.

### Option 2

If you select `Adobe PDF (Print)`, or if you only have one PDF export option when choosing the filename, then in the PDF options dialogue, be sure to make sure `Hyperlinks` is checked in the `Interactive` section.
[image: Hyperlinks Checked in PDF Options]

Answer (score 0):

Select the text and add the hyperlink via the `Hyperlinks` Panel.

Comment: Already done, but nothing changes. In PDF, the text is still just a text.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this in my own document.
I had the same problem, where all but one of my hyperlinks exported to PDF perfectly.
I then realised that the link that I was pasting into the Hyperlinks panel didn't have 'http://' in front; I had pasted in a link that began as www.
Once I added http:// to the beginning of the URL in the panel, it exported into the PDF perfectly.
Hope that helps.